# Jquery tooltip plugin qTip doesn't seem to set width properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, width, qtip

i have an asp.net mvc site and here is a dynamic tooltip using [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/)

Here is my code:

```
$('a.showNutritionInfo').each(function() {

    $(this).qtip({
        content: {
        text: '<img src="../../images/ajax-loader1.gif" alt="" />',
        style: { width: 450 },
        url: '/Tracker/NutritionInfo/' + $(this).attr('id'),
        method: 'get'
        }
    });
});
```

this works perfectly **EXCEPT** the width attribute listed above is ignored.  No matter what i put in that width attribute, i get the same size width tooltip which is about half of the width that i need.  the height is perfectly fine.

any ideas?  is this a bug in the product ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the `style` declaration outside the `content` declaration as those are two different properties:

```
$(this).qtip({
    content: {
        text: '<img src="../../images/ajax-loader1.gif" alt="" />',
        url: '/Tracker/NutritionInfo/' + $(this).attr('id'),
        method: 'get'
    },
    style: { width: 450 }
});
```